# How to update multiple states using Immutability Helper | React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

I am new to Immutability Helper React library, and I am trying to update multiple state values at the same time, but only the last calling method state is getting updated.

this is what I tried:

```
state : {l0: null, l1: null}
updateL0 = (l0) => {
    if(l0){
      this.setState(
        update(this.state, {
          l0: { $set: l0 }
        })
      );
    }
  };
  updateL1 = (l1) => {
    if(l1){
      this.setState(
        update(this.state, {
          l1: { $set: l1 }
        })
      );
    }
  };

Current Output: l1: null, l2: Expected Value

Expected Output: l1: Expected Value , l2: Expected Value
```

Comment: I am not familiar with immutability helper  but try using spread operator like this { l0: { $set: l0 }, l1: { ...state }}. As for each condition you are just l0 or l1 so that's why the other remains default.

Comment: @MontyGoldy [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) does not immediately modify `this.state` so when you use this.state after this.setState you actually get the unmodified version. Since you use immutable state you get the unmodified state (see answer for more information). So using the spread operator would not solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you for coearing that out. @HMR

Answer (score 3):

You can't setState multiple times in one event handler `this.state` may be updated asynchronousl after setState.

From the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.

setState will behave like this:

```
//sate is {name:"Ben",age:22}
this.setState({...this.state,age:23});
console.log(this.state.age);//will log 22
```

So if you setState multiple times in one event handler you are likely to not get the result you were hoping:

```
//sate is {name:"Ben",age:22}
this.setState({...this.state,age:23});
console.log(this.state.age);//will log 22
this.setState({...this.state,name:"Harry"});//age will still be 22
```

The better solution to this is not to use the callback but to write your functions as pure functions (no side effects like setState), pass state to your functions and have them return a new state:

```
updateL0 = (state,l0) => {
  if(l0){
    return update(
      state,
      {
        l0: { $set: l0 }
      }
    );
  }
  return state;
};
updateL1 = (state,l1) => {
  if(l1){
    return update(
      state, 
      {
        l1: { $set: l1 }
      }
    );
  }
  return state;
};
//when you call it you can do:
const newState = updateL0(this.state,L0);
this.setState(updateL1(newState,L1));//note that I'm passing newState here
//or you can just nest updateL1 and updateL0
this.setState(updateL1(updateL0(this.state,L0),L1));
```

Answer (score 0):

use **`spread operator (...)`** in setState method to update multiple state fields as following way

my state is

```
this.state ={
       fields: {
         name:'',
         email: '',
         message: ''
       },
       errors: {},
       disabled : false
}
```

i'm updating

```
this.setState(
  {...this.state, 
   fields:{name:'', email: '', message: ''}, 
   disabled: false
});
```

Comment: if i use this way,and i need to setState another else state?
` this.setState(
                Object.assign(validations, {
                  emailValid: "Email address is not valid."
                })
,
 // {loading:false} => Error Here
              );`